# android picasso .into(new Target() causing method error

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, picasso

We are using the following code to load images into notification .setLargeicon parameter in our android webview app. But unfortunately `.into(new Target() {` displays the following warning:

Class 'Anonymous class derived from Target' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'value()' in 'Target'. We are at loss as what we should do to solve this issue.

```
Picasso.get().load("https://mbracecloud.com/appln_enterprise/images/reconnect_feature7.jpg")
.into(new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, final Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        notificationBuilder1.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
        notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notificationBuilder1.build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        // Do nothing
    }
});
```

**Update:**

Based on inputs given below, we put the following import:

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;
```

and tried to load image, but we are encountering a new error:

```
Class 'Anonymous class derived from Target' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onBitmapFailed(Exception, Drawable)' in 'Target'
```

Please help us out on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you're importing the wrong `Target` and specifically the annotation one. Change

```
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
```

to

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;
```

Comment: added the import as you said, but still encountering error. The error is given above in my question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error `onBitmapFailed(Exception, Drawable)`, you are overriding this method with only `Drawable` parameter but the `Target` class wants to override abstract method with `Exception` and `Drawable` parameters. So, try replacing `onBitmapFailed` with the implementation below:

```
@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(final Exception exception, final Drawable errorDrawable) {
    // Do nothing
}
```